# corner radius doesn't work well in UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, badge, cornerradius

When I added a button to tabbar and set a specific cornerRadius to make it become a circle, I found the `right`of the circle was been clipped , just like

[image: button that is a subview of tabbar]

But it work well in other views, such as UITableViewCell.

[image: button which is in a cell]

I had tried some views like UIImageView and UILabel, but it made no sense.

Does anyone had got into the trouble and fix it up?

Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

By the way, I was working on iPhone6 .

Comment: Sometimes when you are working at small screen size of simulator, it might seems as if it has clipped the view for small UIView. Maybe increase the size of simulator and see the result. Because there wont be a case where same code will clip one view but not other view.

Comment: You could also check the Image Insets for tab bar item.

Comment: I am working on iPhone6.@Manjul Shrestha